# Python animation assumes the wrong focal point of an Ellipse, how to changet it?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a Hohmann transfer in python. The spacecraft travels from Earth to Jupiter using the polar Ellipse equation (r(ß) = a(1 - e^2) / (1 + e*cos(ß)). My animation: [image: The spacecraft path describes an Ellipse]. The problem is that Python assumes the wrong focal point of the Ellipse since an Ellipse has two fixed points, that means, that instead of starting at high velocity due to be closer to the sun (Perihelion), starts at low velocity and ends with high velocity at the  aphelion ( farthest distance to the sun).  Maybe are the x,y coordinates? I'm new with python

This is how it should be:

[image: High velocity closer to the sun]

In which line of my code should I change the assumption of python and reverse or swap the focal points?

'''

```
 import numpy as np
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import animation, rc
 from matplotlib import rcParams



#Plotting the Earth and Jupiter orbits

Earth = plt.Circle((0,0), radius= 1.0,fill=False,color='blue') 
Jupiter = plt.Circle((0,0), radius= 5.2,fill=False,color='green',linewidth=2)

#Moving Earth, Jupiter, and Spacecraft
patch_E = plt.Circle((0.0, 0.0),radius=0.05,fill=True,color='blue')
patch_J = plt.Circle((0.0, 0.0),radius=0.14,fill=True,color='green')
patch_H = plt.Circle((0.0, 0.0),radius=0.03,fill=True,color='red')
  
#equations for the path calcualtion of the ellipse
ra = 5.2 #orbits radius
rp = 1.0 # units [AU] = astronomical units
sun_const = 0.00029 # AU^3/ (days)^2
a = (ra + rp)/2 #semi major axis
e = (ra - rp)/(ra + rp) #eccentricity
# 1AU = 149597870691 m
Period = 2*np.pi*np.sqrt((a**3)/(sun_const)) # Time it takes for a full ellipse path, the half 
#is for the transfer
alpha = 180 - (360*Period/(2*4383)) #angle for jupiter to be ahead for the transfer, 4383 
#days, the days it takes jupiter to orbit the sun, Period should be divided by 2

def init(): 
 patch_E.center = (0.0,0.0)
 ax.add_patch(patch_E)
 patch_J.center = (0.0,0.0)
 ax.add_patch(patch_J)
 patch_H.center = (0.0,0.0)
 ax.add_patch(patch_H)
 return patch_E,patch_J,patch_H,

def animate(i): #Animation function, i*10 makes the animation faster
#Earth
  x_E, y_E = patch_E.center
  x_E = np.cos((2*np.pi/365.2)*i*10)
  y_E = np.sin((2*np.pi/365.2)*i*10)
  patch_E.center = (x_E, y_E)
#Jupiter
  x_J, y_J = patch_J.center
  x_J = 5.2*np.cos((2*np.pi/4383)*i*10+(np.pi*alpha/180.))
  y_J = 5.2*np.sin((2*np.pi/4383)*i*10+(np.pi*alpha/180.))
  patch_J.center = (x_J,y_J)
#Hohmann
#Ellipse Equation r(ß) = a*(1 - e^2)/(1 + e*cos (ß))

   x_H = a*(1. - e**2)/(1. + e*np.cos((2*np.pi/Period)*i*10))*np.cos((2*np.pi/Period)*i*10)
   y_H = a*(1. - e**2)/(1. + e*np.cos((2*np.pi/Period)*i*10))*np.sin((2*np.pi/Period)*i*10)
   patch_H.center = (x_H,y_H)
   return patch_E,patch_J,patch_H,

rcParams['animation.convert_path'] = r'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\convert'
rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'   #converting the animation 
into a gif


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))  #config and plots the whole animation
fig.subplots_adjust(left=.15, bottom=.16, right=.99, top=.97)
ax.set_facecolor('black')
ax.plot(0,0,color='orange',marker='o',
linestyle='',markersize=16,markerfacecolor='yellow',label='Sun')

ax.plot([],[],color='blue',linestyle='',marker='o',label='Earth')
ax.plot([],[],color='green',linestyle='',marker='o',label='Jupiter')
ax.plot([],[],color='red',linestyle='',marker='o',label='spacecraft')
ax.add_patch(Earth) # puts the on the corner the labes
ax.add_patch(Jupiter)
ax.set_xlabel('X [AU]',fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Y [AU]',fontsize=12)
ax.legend(loc='best',fontsize=12)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func = 
animate,init_func=init,frames=360,interval=10,blit=True) # animates the code frames = 200
plt.axis('scaled') #Scale the plot in real time
#anim.save('Hohmann_Jupiter.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps = 60, bitrate=1800 ) # saves the 
#animation as gif

plt.show()
```

'''

Comment: What do you mean python in assuming something wrong about the ellipse? Is it in the animation or in the calculations you made? Also, when you set the Circle patch centers to the values you calculated with the ellipse equation, why didn't you use an Ellipse patch?

Comment: Just being pedantic here. You are *animating* a hohmann transfer, not *simulating*. There is no integration of the equations of motion here and therefore you are not simulating the physics of the hohmann transfer. You'd either need to be using patched conics or n-body gravitation to accurately *simulate* the forces on the spacecraft that determine its trajectory.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315386/ -- to me it looks like you may be using the wrong theta, but it's pretty difficult to follow your code, it's quite messy.

Comment: @K.Cl I didn't know about the Ellipse patch since I am new to python.

Comment: @ddejohn English is not my first language so yeah simulation slipped out of my vocabulary but yeah. It's only an animation. Since is small proyect that I am doing I didnt want to put make it really a big deal. I know the three body problem and the gravity assits as well but I want to make it simplier

Comment: @ddejohn If you see in my code in the part #Hohmann u will see that the equation that equals to the equation of your link. You have to scroll down in your link to the second answer  is the equation (7) and you will see the equation r(theta) = a(1 - e ^2) / (1+ e*cos(theta)

Comment: But which theta are you using in your equation, true anomaly, eccentric anomaly, or mean anomaly? To me it looks like you're using mean anomaly, when I think you need the eccentric anomaly. It's been a while since I fiddled with astrodynamics though.

Comment: In the `animate` function when you are computing `x_H, y_H` you are assuming that an object placed on an elliptic orbit travels at a constant angular speed. This is clearly wrong. As mentioned before, you need to integrate the equation of motion over an orbit!

Comment: @ddejohn The  angle is the true anomaly.  I din't want to code the mean and the eccentric anomaly since I need to code with time as a factor or the newton numerical method

Comment: But what I'm saying is that `2 pi / period` is the mean anomaly, not the true anomaly.

Comment: @ddejohn I found a better solution. Instead of using equation in polar coordinates I used the x,y equation. 

'      x_H = a*cos(2*np,pi*i*10/Period)  - (a-1)      '

and: 
'y_H = b*sin(2*np,pi*i*10/Period) '
 where: ' b = a*np.sqrt(1-e**2)' , 'a = (ra+rp)/2' ,  'e = (ra-rp)/ra+rp'  , 'ra = 5.2   rp = 1'

Now there is no angular velocity and the spacecraft moves with constant velocity

Comment: If you insist on avoiding integrating the equations of motion, then you could probably use [this expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed#Instantaneous_orbital_speed) for the orbital velocity of a body given its distance `r`, the semi-major axis `a`, and the gravitational parameter `mu`.